# compiling assembly from the other just compiled assembly

Tags: vb.net, codedom, in-memory

I need to compile assembly in memory, that can compile another one. There is a form with one button. Here is a code of the form

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.CodeDom
Imports System.CodeDom.Compiler
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Public Class testtwo
    Shared str_tb As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Call openkubik()
    End Sub
    Private Sub openkubik()
        Dim th As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf sborkakub)
        th.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub sborkakub()
        Dim evi As System.Security.Policy.Evidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence
        Dim assemblyDomain As AppDomain
        Dim assemblyDomainSetup As AppDomainSetup = New AppDomainSetup
        assemblyDomainSetup.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory
        assemblyDomainSetup.DisallowBindingRedirects = False
        assemblyDomainSetup.DisallowCodeDownload = True
        assemblyDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
        assemblyDomainSetup.LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost
        assemblyDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AssemblyDomain", evi, assemblyDomainSetup)
        assemblyDomain.DoCallBack(AddressOf assamblykub)
        Call assamblykub()
    End Sub
    Private Shared Sub assamblykub()
        Call createtext()
        Dim objCodeCompiler As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider = System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VB")
        Dim objCompilerParameters As New System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters()
        For Each asm In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(asm.Location)
        Next
        objCompilerParameters.CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe"
        objCompilerParameters.GenerateExecutable = True
        objCompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = True
        objCompilerParameters.IncludeDebugInformation = False
        Dim objCompileResults As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults = objCodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(objCompilerParameters, str_tb)
        If objCompileResults.Errors.HasErrors Then
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error: Line>{0}, {1} # {2}", objCompileResults.Errors(0).Line, objCompileResults.Errors(0).ErrorText, objCompileResults.Errors(0).ErrorNumber))
            Return
        End If
        Dim objAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = objCompileResults.CompiledAssembly
        Dim objTheClass As Object = objAssembly.CreateInstance("MainClass")
        If objTheClass Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Can't load class...")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Try
            objTheClass.GetType.InvokeMember("Main", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, _
            Nothing, objTheClass, Nothing)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error:" & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Shared Sub createtext()
        Dim tempfile As New IO.FileStream(Application.StartupPath & "/temp_open.txt", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
        Dim tempfilesr As New IO.StreamReader(tempfile, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251))
        str_tb = tempfilesr.ReadToEnd
        tempfilesr.Close()
        tempfile.Close()
        tempfile = Nothing
        tempfilesr = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the code of "temp_open.txt" file

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Windows
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
  Public Class MainClass 
Inherits MarshalByRefObject
    Public Shared Sub Main()
     Dim tf As New testtwo
    application.run(tf)
    End Sub
End Class
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class testtwo
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
        components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub
        Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Me.SuspendLayout()
       Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(114, 40)
        Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(231, 39)
        Me.Button1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Button1.Text = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(465, 133)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
        Me.Name = "test"
        Me.Text = "test"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
   End Sub
       Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
End Class
Public Class testtwo
    Shared str_tb As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Call openkubik()
    End Sub
    Private Sub openkubik()
        Dim th As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf sborkakub)
        th.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub sborkakub()
        Dim evi As System.Security.Policy.Evidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence
        Dim assemblyDomain As AppDomain
        Dim assemblyDomainSetup As AppDomainSetup = New AppDomainSetup
        assemblyDomainSetup.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory
        assemblyDomainSetup.DisallowBindingRedirects = False
        assemblyDomainSetup.DisallowCodeDownload = True
        assemblyDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
        assemblyDomainSetup.LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost
        assemblyDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AssemblyDomain", evi, assemblyDomainSetup)
        assemblyDomain.DoCallBack(AddressOf assamblykub)
    End Sub
    Private Shared Sub assamblykub()
        Call createtext()
        Dim objCodeCompiler As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider = System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VB")
        Dim objCompilerParameters As New System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters()
        dim asm as System.Reflection.Assembly
    For Each asm In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(asm.Location)
        Next
        'objCompilerParameters.OutputAssembly = "res1"
        objCompilerParameters.CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe"
        objCompilerParameters.GenerateExecutable = True
        objCompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = True
        objCompilerParameters.IncludeDebugInformation = False
        Dim objCompileResults As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults = objCodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(objCompilerParameters, str_tb)
        If objCompileResults.Errors.HasErrors Then
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error: Line>{0}, {1} # {2}", objCompileResults.Errors(0).Line, objCompileResults.Errors(0).ErrorText, objCompileResults.Errors(0).ErrorNumber))
            Return
        End If
        Dim objAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = objCompileResults.CompiledAssembly
        Dim objTheClass As Object = objAssembly.CreateInstance("MainClass")
        If objTheClass Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Can't load class...")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Try
            objTheClass.GetType.InvokeMember("Main", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, _
            Nothing, objTheClass, Nothing)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error:" & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Shared Sub createtext()
        Dim tempfile As New IO.FileStream(Application.StartupPath & "/temp_open.txt", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
        Dim tempfilesr As New IO.StreamReader(tempfile, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251))
        str_tb = tempfilesr.ReadToEnd
        tempfilesr.Close()
        tempfile.Close()
        tempfile = Nothing
        tempfilesr = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I click Button1 in first form -> appears second form. but when I click Button 1 in the second form I have an FileNotFound Exception. What am I doing wrong?
There is an interesting moment. This example with some changes work in C#(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729403/compilling-assembly-from-the-other-just-compilled-assembly) Maybe There are people who knows vb and c# and helps me to understand differences between two examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to replace `assemblyDomain.DoCallBack(AddressOf assamblykub)` with simple call of `assamblykub` function ?

Comment: yes i did, i have the same problem, that i had when add the new appdomain creation. exception "vbc : Command line (0,0) : error BC2006: option 'r' requires':<file_list>'"

Comment: the problem was in
dim asm as System.Reflection.Assembly
    For Each asm In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(asm.Location)
        Next

have to be 
`objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")` 

and so on

Anton Semenov, thank you for help